# rstudio hangs and aborts with rmarkdown loop

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have several datasets each of which have a common grouping factor. I want to produce one large report with separate sections for each grouping factor. Therefore I want to re-run a set of `rmarkdown` code for each iteration of the grouping factor.

Using the following approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269675/loop-in-r-markdown) doesnt work for me. i.e.:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
output: html_document
---


```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:2){
cat('\n')  
cat("#This is a heading for ", i, "\n") 
hist(cars[,i])
cat('\n') 
}
```
````

Because the markdown I want to run on each grouping factor does not easily fit within one code chunk. The report must be ordered by grouping factor and I want to be able to come in and out of code chunks for each iteration over grouping factor.

So I went for calling an `Rmd.` with render using a loop from an Rscript for each grouping factor as found [here](http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/software/R/markdown_multiple_reports.html):

```
# run a markdown file to summarise each one.
for(each_group in the_groups){
render("/Users/path/xx.Rmd",
       output_format = "pdf_document",
       output_file =  paste0(each_group,"_report_", Sys.Date(),".pdf"), 
       output_dir = "/Users/path/folder")
}
```

My plan was to then combine the individual reports with `pdftk`. However, when I get to the about the 5th iteration my Rstudio session hangs and eventually aborts with a fatal error. I have ran individually the `Rmd.` for the grouping factors it stops at which work fine.

I tested some looping with the following simple test files:

`.R`

```
# load packages
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)

# use first 5 rows of mtcars as example data
mtcars <- mtcars[1:5,]


# for each type of car in the data create a report
# these reports are saved in output_dir with the name specified by output_file
for (car in rep(unique(rownames(mtcars)), 100)){
  # for pdf reports  
  rmarkdown::render(input = "/Users/xx/Desktop/2.Rmd", 
                    output_format = "pdf_document",
                    output_file = paste("test_report_", car, Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep=''),
                    output_dir = "/Users/xx/Desktop")

}
```

`.Rmd`

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
# packages
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r}
# limit data to car name that is currently specified by the loop  
cars <- mtcars[rownames(mtcars)==car,]

# create example data for each car 
x <- sample(1:10, 1)
cars <- do.call("rbind", replicate(x, cars, simplify = FALSE))

# create hypotheical lat and lon for each row in cars 
cars$lat <- sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, 30, 46), 3))
cars$lon <- sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, -115, -80),3))

cars
```

Today is `r Sys.Date()`.

```{r}
# data table of cars sold 
table <- xtable(cars[,c(1:2, 12:13)])
print(table, type="latex", comment = FALSE)
```
````

This works fine. So I also looked at memory pressure while running my actual loop over the `Rmd.` which gets very high.

- Is there a way to reduce memory when looping over a render call to an `Rmd.` file?
- Is there a better way to create a report for multiple grouping factors than looping over a render call to an `Rmd.` file, which doesn't rely on the entire loop being inside one code chunk?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here [rmarkdown::render() in a loop - cannot allocate vector of size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887792/rmarkdownrender-in-a-loop-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size)

knitr::knit_meta(class=NULL, clean = TRUE)

use this line before the render line and it seems to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Internal Links are often a so named **possible duplicate**. You may give a hint by adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same issue now and it's very **perplexing**. I tried to create some simple MWEs but they loop successfully on occasion. So far, I've tried

1. Checking the garbage collection between iterations of **rmarkdown::render**. (They don't reveal any special accumulations.)
2. Removing all inessential objects
3. Deleting any cached files manually

Here is my question:

> How can we debug hangs? Should we set up special log files to understand what's going wrong?

Comment: I have a found a solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893358/looping-through-code-in-knitr-and-rmarkdown?rq=1 .  The downside to using child rmarkdown files as described in that solution is that one cannot use external chunks. Instead, the calculations and figures must exist in the child document and must be UNLABELED. Otherwise the iterations overwrite one another. This doesn't solve the hang and crash from looping rmarkdown::render but it is an effective workaround for me.

Comment: Did you find out anything new about this since?