# How to knit_print flextable with loop in a rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, flextable

I am trying to produce mutltiple tables using the **flextable** and **kable** packages. When I want to output some table  iteratively, I found `knit_print` of flextable is not working in loop. Below is a minimal example:

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
 data(cars)
     speed<-unique(cars$speed)
for (v in 1:length(speed)) {
  carspd<-cars[which(cars$speed==speed[v]),]
  tb<-regulartable(carspd)
knit_print(tb)
}
knit_print(tb)
```
````

Just the last `knit_print` can print the result to the word_document with the `.Rmd` file.

---

Now I find the difference of them in `.md` which is output by the pandoc process file with ultraedit,
the right table:

````
```{=openxml}
<w:tbl xmlns:w=".......
````

the wrong table:

```
鈥媊``{=openxml}
<w:tbl xmlns:w="
```

In hexadecimal there are extra content:"E2 80 8B", someone call they Zero-Width Space? But I am not figure out how to avoid it.

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to Stackoverflow. A good first question, but I made a couple of edits to make it clearer and for the code to be fully reproducible. Hope it helps for future reference :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using flextable in r markdown loop not producing tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670817/using-flextable-in-r-markdown-loop-not-producing-tables)

Comment: @MichaelHarper thank you. I searched but missed it. I will look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of one of the functions that `flextable` uses in its `knit_print` method:  `knitr::asis_output()` can't be used in a loop.  A couple of solutions are described here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1137.

This one works for me in HTML output, just collecting all the output into one big vector and printing it at the end.  I have modified the code to also insert some text before the table and a figure after it.
I don't use Word, but I'd assume it will also work there:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
data(cars)
speed <- unique(cars$speed)
results <- character()
for (v in 1:length(speed)) {
  carspd <- cars[which(cars$speed == speed[v]),]
  tb <- regulartable(carspd)

  # Generate a figure in a temporary file
  filename <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  png(filename)
  hist(carspd$dist)
  dev.off()

  # Put everything into the results vector
  results <- c(results, "\n\nThis is the table for v =", v,
                        knit_print(tb),
                        knitr:::wrap(include_graphics(filename)))

}
asis_output(results)
knit_print(tb)
```
````

A couple of notes:

- The `\n\n` in the text seems to be necessary to insert a line break.
- The `knitr:::wrap()` function is an undocumented internal function in `knitr`, so there might be limitations that I don't know about, and this might fail in some future version of `knitr`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try. But it looks like difficult because I want to insert some sentences and pictures between the tables.