# Looping Flextables in R Markdown documents with Word output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, flextable

I am looking to print multiple flextables in a single R Markdown document. This is not challenging when using html output, but I need Word output.

With html output, the following R Markdown code (example taken from https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/offcran/examples.html#looping-in-r-mardown-documents) produces a document with multiple Flextables:

````
---
output:
  html_document: default

---

```{r}
library(htmltools)
library(flextable)

ft <- flextable(head(iris))
tab_list <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  tab_list[[i]] <- tagList(
    tags$h6(paste0("iteration ", i)),
    htmltools_value(ft)
  )
}
tagList(tab_list)
```
````

I have been unable to get an equivalent output using Word document output. 
The solution proposed in
[How to knit_print flextable with loop in a rmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629692/how-to-knit-print-flextable-with-loop-in-a-rmd-file) similarly works fine with html output, but I have failed to get this to render correctly with Word output.

Any advice on a R Markdown Word document output equivalent of the above example would be very helpful!

Comment: Loop or not, I hope someone can provide a better way than I know of to make tables for Word (or other non LaTeX word processor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `flextable::docx_value` and the chunk option `results='asis'`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
```

```{r results='asis'}
ft <- flextable(head(iris))
for(i in 1:3){
  cat("<w:p/>")## add this to add an empty  new paragraph between tables
  flextable::docx_value(ft)
}
```
````

Comment: Straight from the package developer! Nice!