# looping flextable from a list does not create tables in Word

Tags: list, loops, datatables, r-markdown, flextable

I have series of tables I created from a list. I'm using `flextable()` in `R-Markdown` to output them to a Word document and I'd like to separate them into one table per page. The workaround from this [earlier posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670817/using-flextable-in-r-markdown-loop-not-producing-tables) doesn't fit my issue.  Below is my reproducible code:

````
```{r  echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

my_list <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$Species))

for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  myft <- flextable(my_list[[i]]) %>%
    set_caption(paste0("Table ", as.roman(i),".\n", names(my_list[i]), ".")) %>%
    padding(padding = 1.5, part = "all")
  print(myft)
  cat("\n\n")
}

```
````

What I get in my output is this:

```
## a flextable object.
## col_keys: `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species` 
## header has 1 row(s) 
## body has 50 row(s) 
## original dataset sample: 
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 
## 
## a flextable object.
## col_keys: `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species` 
## header has 1 row(s) 
## body has 50 row(s) 
## original dataset sample: 
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
## 1          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
## 2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
## 3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
## 4          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
## 5          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
## 
## 
## a flextable object.
## col_keys: `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species` 
## header has 1 row(s) 
## body has 50 row(s) 
## original dataset sample: 
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
## 1          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
## 2          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
## 3          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
## 4          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
## 5          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello, the workaround you are using is not valid anymore. Read this https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html#looping-in-r-mardown-documents, it explains how to do it

Comment: @DavidGohel Awesome! Thanks for the reply. Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved the above issue based on David Gohel's reply.

````
```{r  results='asis'}

library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

#Print annual yield and area per field

my_list <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  split(f = as.factor(.$Species))

for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  myft <- flextable(my_list[[i]]) %>%
    set_caption(paste0("Table ", as.roman(i),".\n", names(my_list[i]), ".")) %>%
    padding(padding = 1.5, part = "all")
  cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n") #added this bit to break page per table
  flextable_to_rmd(myft)
}

```
````