# Printing flextables from a list of lists in R-markdown

Tags: r, list, for-loop, r-markdown, flextable

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(flextable)
datA <- fread("anyvar somevar
               2  4
               2  3
               2  5")

dat_list <- list("one" = list("datA" = datA, "datB" = 2*datA),"two" = list("datC" = 3*datA, "datD" = 4*datA), "three" = list("datE" = 5*datA, "datF" = 6*datA))

for (i in seq_along(dat_list) ) {
  for (j in seq_along( dat_list[[i]] ) ) {
    dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- flextable( dat_list[[i]][[j]] )
  }
}
```

I want to print out part of this list in `R-markdown`. In R I can just use the print function in a for loop:

```
 for (j in seq_along(dat_list[[2]])) {
    print(dat_list[[2]][[j]])
 }
```

However in R-markdown I cannot. I tried using `print` and `return`, but it is not giving me the right output (print does not print a flextable, and return, returns only the first table). How should I do this? :

````
---
output: word_document
---

My example data:

```{r}

library(data.table)
library(flextable)
datA <- fread("anyvar somevar
               2  4
               2  3
               2  5")

dat_list <- list("one" = list("datA" = datA, "datB" = 2*datA),"two" = list("datC" = 3*datA, "datD" = 4*datA), "three" = list("datE" = 5*datA, "datF" = 6*datA))


for (i in seq_along(dat_list) ) {
  for (j in seq_along( dat_list[[i]] ) ) {
    dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- flextable( dat_list[[i]][[j]] )
  }
}

```

Print function

```{r, echo=FALSE}

 for (j in seq_along(dat_list[[2]])) {
    print(dat_list[[2]][[j]])
    cat("\n\newpage\n")
 }
```

Return function

```{r, echo=FALSE}

 for (j in seq_along(dat_list[[2]])) {
    return(dat_list[[2]][[j]])
    cat("\n\newpage\n")
 }
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667505/12993861) you could use `knitr::knit_print` and add `results='asis'` to the chunk options. Also note that we have to use `\\newpage` to add the page break.

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(data.table)
library(flextable)
datA <- fread("anyvar somevar
               2  4
               2  3
               2  5")

dat_list <- list("one" = list("datA" = datA, "datB" = 2 * datA), "two" = list("datC" = 3 * datA, "datD" = 4 * datA), "three" = list("datE" = 5 * datA, "datF" = 6 * datA))


for (i in seq_along(dat_list)) {
  for (j in seq_along(dat_list[[i]])) {
    dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- flextable(dat_list[[i]][[j]])
  }
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (j in seq_along(dat_list[[2]])) {
  cat(knitr::knit_print(dat_list[[2]][[j]]))
  cat("\n\\newpage\n")
}
```
````

[image]